# What am I missing in my Eloquent Javascript, Chessboard code?

Tags: javascript, loops

I've been working on the chessboard challenge from Eloquent Javascript for quite a while now and I keep getting closer and closer.

Below is my latest code. The first line in the string prints correctly but after the first line, the loop only prints \n and doesn't add any new space characters or hashtags. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction? What is missing from my loop?

```
let a = '';
let y = 0;

for (x = 0; x < 8 ; x++, a += '\n') {
    while (y < 9) {
        if (x + y % 2) {
            a += '#';
            y ++;
        } else {
            a += ' ';
            y ++;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Thank you all for the help! I've made the appropriate changes and, of course, it works! I was so close this time that I knew it had to be something small, such as resetting y and adding the parentheses.

Thanks again! I was stuck on this challenge for a very long time and was doing my best not to look up the solution. But we all need help every now and then.

Happy coding!

Comment: You should reset `y` after the first iteration of the outer loop completes. But then, why not an inner `for` loop, similar to the outer loop, but on `y`?

Comment: Your code never resets the value of `y`. Also `x` should also be explicitly declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a for loop instead of while. First of all, you forgot to reset the value of `y`. Second of all, you increment `y` both in `if` and `else`, so you might as well always increment it at the end of the while body, which can be replaced with a for loop. Also, you need to surround `x + y` with parentheses in the `x + y % 2` expression because modulo operator has precedence over addition operator, so it should be `(x + y) % 2`. With these changes, your code would look like:

```js
let a = '';

for (let x = 0; x < 8; x++, a += '\n') {
    for(let y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        if ((x + y) % 2) {
            a += '#';
        } else {
            a += ' ';
        }
    }
}

console.log(a)
```